# Sending values from a range of cells on one worksheet to a range of cells on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the 1004 error when trying to send values from one sheet to another sheet in the same Excel 2016 workbook.  Sheet A is the active sheet.

This code works

```
Sheets("A").Range(Cells(m+1,2),Cells(TgtRow-180,2)=Sheets("B).Range("B181:B363")
```

I've tried several variations of the code I'd like to get to work, but resorted to try and get this to work

```
Sheets("A").Range(Cells(m+1,2),Cells(TgtRow-180,2)=Sheets("B).Range(Cells(183,2),Cells(363,2)
```

to try and figure out where I am going wrong.  Should be the same as using the other notation, but I'm still getting the 1004 error. I'm sure it is a simple fix, but I can't find it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: please disregard the missing ) and the end of the faulty code string.

Comment: `Cells` needs a worksheet qualifier, or it defaults to the active sheet.